# Define a perpendicular plane to the vector

Tags: discrete-mathematics, vector-spaces, normed-spaces, 3d, plane-geometry

I want to define a perpendicular plane to the vector (2, 3, 4). The plane passes through the origin. And I want to define arbitrary points on this plane.

Comment: Can you write the condition for $(x,y,z)$ belonging to the plane ?

Comment: A single vector in 3D space is contained in infinitely many planes. A plane perpendicular to any one of them (meaning a dihedral angle of $\pi/2$ between the planes) could be considered perpendicular to the original vector if it doesn't contain it (I wouldn't, but I'm making an allowance for it), of which there are infinitely many. So which one would you like? If you want a _unique_ plane, you need two vectors.

Comment: @H.sapiensrex Wouldn't that result in every plane that doesn't contain the designated vector?  Usually, "plane perpendicular to a vector" means that we're talking about the plane's normal vector, so we don't need a second vector.  Or are you thinking of a plane containing (2,3,4)?

Comment: @Teepeemm yes, I was thinking of a plane containing said vector. I've realised my error: I missed the part of OP's question that said "The plane passes through the origin", so that's my bad lol

Answer (score 3):

STRONG HINT

Planes perpendicular to the vector $(2,3,4)$ have equation $$2x+3y+4z=c.$$
Can you now see what value the constant $c$ must take?

Answer (score 2):

The plane is $\pi:\ 2x+3y+4z=0$. It passes through the origin clearly, and its perpendicular to the line $L=span(2,3,4)$. This is because every vector $v\in \pi$ obviouly satisfies the equation of the plane, and so, when doing the dot product with the vector $(2,3,4)$ gives $0$, thus is orthogonal.